# Light blinking detection in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to detect a blinking light as captured by the phone's camera? No filming, just turn on camera and detect any blinking lights captured.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question, but having a user name like mine, I simply must add your question to the list of my favorites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, without any coding this is not possible.

To program this is you would need to do this:

Use [the Camera/Photo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202975%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to [capture frames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.videosink%28VS.95%29.aspx) and do some image analysis to find areas going lighter and darker.

Comment: Thanks @Erno, that's just what I want. I still don't have a phone, so I was just scouting the terrain. As soon as I get one I'll begin developing.